# Register for Remote AND Local Notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, apple-push-notifications

In my app I want to support both - `Remote Notifications` and `Local Notifications`. The `Remote Notification` should have two actions that let the user interact with it in Notification Center.

Currently I have this code to register for notifications. My question is do I have to call register for local notifications separately or are local notifications already included in this registration process.

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *actionCancel = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    [actionCancel setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
    [actionCancel setTitle:@"Cancel"];
    [actionCancel setIdentifier:NotificationActionOneIdent];
    [actionCancel setDestructive:NO];
    [actionCancel setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *actionOk = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    [actionOk setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
    [actionOk setTitle:@"Ok"];
    [actionOk setIdentifier:NotificationActionTwoIdent];
    [actionOk setDestructive:NO];
    [actionOk setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

    UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *actionCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
    [actionCategory setIdentifier:NotificationCategoryIdent];
    [actionCategory setActions:@[actionCancel, actionOk]
                    forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];

    NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObject:actionCategory];
    UIUserNotificationType types = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|
                                    UIUserNotificationTypeSound|
                                    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);

    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings;
    settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types
                                                 categories:categories];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

Comment: For registration, it's the same API.  If you have permission for one, you have for the other.

Comment: Actually, when there are different notification settings, you should register for the new notification settings again. New notification settings may differ from the previously registered settings.

Answer (score 0):

locals are included when you registerUserNotificationSettings so your code is fine

Comment: Code looks good except this line: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];` where he is trying to register for remote notifications without waiting for user's decision to allow the notification settings or not.

Comment: How can I wait and react on the user's decision? I used the code from the apple documentation. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html

Comment: wait for 2 calls: `
- application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:` and
`- application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:`